# Patterns of accent changes by non-native English speakers

Tags: phonetics, english, phonemes

I am looking for a list of 'accent changes', or pronunciation inaccuracies, non-native English speakers commonly make when speaking English words.  The list would obviously be native language specific and it would be great of the information had the form of phoneme to phoneme mapping.

A [tool I wrote](http://shape-of-code.coding-guidelines.com/2012/03/16/generating-sounds-like-and-accented-words/) attempts to generate words (actually letter sequences that may or may not be existing English words) that sound-like the input word.  slike (the name of the tool) does a simple job of 'sounding' German and I would like to do a better job, as well as support other languages.

Comment: Hello Derek and welcome to Linguistics! :) There is a mistake in your question but I don't know what you meant there... It's this part: *"...the input **word. slike** does a simple job..."*

Comment: You'd have to look for one separate list of changes per language I'm afraid. After all, a German accent is not the same as a French accent.

Comment: Alenanno, Kaleissin, thanks for your comments.  I have updated the wording to be more explicit.

Comment: An interesting question. The first thing that comes to my mind is the book "Accents and Dialects for Stage and Screen". There's a special chapter on foreign language accents. You can also see/hear some stuff on the publisher's website (scroll down to "Foreign-Language Accents"), http://www.paulmeier.com/booklets.html

Comment: this question might be more appropriate for English.SE.